# SwiftUI - unexpected behavior with custom transition modifying frame size

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to implement a custom transition in SwiftUI which animates the frame size. In my example, I am using a Circle with a static lineWidth.

What I want is that if the Circle gets inserted, it should be a little bit bigger at first and then shrink to its "normal" size. For deletion, I want that the circle gets a little bit bigger.

I can't use the scale transition since I want the lineWidth to stay the same all the time.

My custom transition works for the insertion, but not for the deletion progress (the frame size stays the same). I can't figure out why it is not working. Maybe messing up with frame sizes is not optimal? (I have also tried to do something similar with .padding but that didn't work as well)

I know that I could do that with State variables and without transitions but I figured out that transitions are way more reliable than the former (at least in my special use case). So, I really want to do this with transitions.

Does somebody have an idea how to fix this?

[image]

```
struct ShapeClipModifier: ViewModifier {
    let percent: CGFloat
    let normalFrame: CGFloat = 100
    let biggerFrame: CGFloat = 200
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        let diff: CGFloat = biggerFrame - normalFrame
        let currentFrame = normalFrame + percent * diff
        return content.frame(width: currentFrame, height: currentFrame, alignment: .center)
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var switched = false
    let transition = AnyTransition.modifier(active: ShapeClipModifier(percent: 1), identity: ShapeClipModifier(percent: 0))
     
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Spacer()
                if(switched){
                    Circle()
                        .stroke(lineWidth: 30)
                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                        .transition(transition.combined(with: AnyTransition.opacity).animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)))
                }
            Spacer()
            
            Toggle("Turn on", isOn: $switched.animation()).padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftUI doesn't know how to animate your `ShapeClipModifier` so first thing you have to conform it to `AnimatableModifier` and add an `animatableData` to it:

```swift
var animatableData: CGFloat {
    get { percent }
    set { percent = newValue }
}
```

Another thing is not obvious at all - you need to wrap your `content` in your `ShapeClipModifier.body(content:)` into something like `Color.clear` , so:

```swift
func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    let diff: CGFloat = biggerFrame - normalFrame
    let currentFrame = normalFrame + percent * diff
    return Color.clear.overlay(
        content.frame(
            width: currentFrame,
            height: currentFrame,
            alignment: .center
        )
    )
}
```

If you're interested in more details head on to [SwiftUI Lab](https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-animations-part3/).

It works for me™️

Comment: Thank you so much! Strange that the Color.clear thing is still not resolved...